# C what happens putting int* as parameter where parameter type is int**?

Tags: c, pointers, parameter-passing

What happens when I put a pointer `int*` as parameter where the parameter type is a pointer of pointers `int**`?

```
int main(..) {
    int* local_arr = malloc( 10 * sizeof(int) );
    func(local_arr)
}

void func(int** par) {...}
```

Comment: If the passed value doesn't match the declaration, besides getting a stern warning from the compiler (if it allow the conversion at all) you will have *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you will  atleast get a warning about it.

But as function would be written keeping `int **` parameter in mind, so there may be a case where you dereference it two times which would be a problem if you pass `int *`, thus, causing undefined behaviour. 
Also, type mismatch would happen in function body in such case.

Answer (score 2):

Passing an `int *` parameter for an `int **` argument without an explicit cast is a *constraint violation* in C. C language does not support implicit conversion of `int *` value to `int **` type. Your program is not a valid C program and the compiler is required to tell you about it through diagnostic messages.

In other words, this is what is colloquially referred to as "compile error" in C. Your program is "non-compilable".

Even if some non-pedantic C compiler agrees to compile this program, this is not a C program and behavior of your code is not defined by C language.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens (except warnings) if the sizeof(int) equals to sizeof(int*), the error happening when you want to deference int** argument with **, if you deference it with single * nothing wrong will happen, however it isn't good practice.

```
void funct(int ** arg){
    printf("%i", (int) *arg);
}

int i = 5;
funct((int **) &arg); // will print 5
```

Also be aware, it's ABI dependent and may not work everywhere